# WPF MediaElement fullscreen controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

Ill keep this simple, I have a mediaelementcontrol playing full screen using the following code

```
canvasMovieCategoryItem.Children.Remove(uiMediaPlayer);

uiMediaPlayer.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
uiMediaPlayer.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;

this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
this.Content = uiMediaPlayer;
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

This all works nicely.

Does anyone know a way of adding a panel at the bottom when you move the mouse with buttons  to control elements of the active media element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own player by using user control mechanism. Create a user control insert a panel at bottom and a mediaelement.

Then control the panel by mouseMove event of the userControl when mouse position in a certain area make your panel visible.And when it moves from that certain area make it hidden.

hope you got the idea and it helps.